# How much of published papers is reasonable to expect to "fail" somehow? E.g. not having the impact you planned

Tags: publications, bibliometrics

How much of published papers is reasonable to expect to "fail" somehow? E.g. not having the impact you planned

Are there studies that would e.g. measure, how much of published papers become lesser than expected or become obsolete faster, than expected? Or the kinds of issues.

Comment: I don't know why this question is closed: while the question is subjective, I think it's a common X-Y question with an objective answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is a question not about science, but about personal expectations.

Consider the following different perspectives on the same set of papers, some well received and some poorly received:

- All of these papers have failed, because I am not famous yet.
- Some of these papers have succeeded and some have failed, because my community embraced some and ignored others.
- All of these papers have succeeded, because the response to them has given me an objective assessment of how interested my community is in these pieces of work.

I recommend taking the latter approach and considering the impact of a paper part of its effective peer review and feedback for you with regards to your research choices.

Comment: I think that Albert Einstein had to wait quite a while before his ideas became mainstream. I've heard it said that the scientific establishment of the day had to die or retire so that younger and more open researchers came to the fore.

Comment: @Buffy Planck's principle: "A new scientific truth does not triumph by convincing its opponents and making them see the light, but rather because its opponents eventually die and a new generation grows up that is familiar with it. . . . An important scientific innovation rarely makes its way by gradually winning over and converting its opponents: it rarely happens that Saul becomes Paul. What does happen is that its opponents gradually die out, and that the growing generation is familiarized with the ideas from the beginning: another instance of the fact that the future lies with the youth."

Answer (score 2):

If "failed" means "not having the impact planned" then hell, it is probably close to one-hundred percent!

However, I think that's the wrong way to look at this.  You can control the quality of your paper, but you can't control its impact (though perhaps you can influence it with some good marketing).  If you write a high-quality paper that adds useful knowledge that is available to society, that is a great success in my view, even if no-one appreciates it.  Obviously it is unfortunate if your good paper has little impact, and that matters, but it is not a reason to consider the work a failure.

Comment: This is interesting, because I perceive that often people are positively biased prior to publishing. After all, why would they publish, if they weren't ascertained that it's "worthwhile". And sometimes publications may be glorified just because "they were published". W/o considering, whether their "impact" is significant. Obviously a paper that becomes cited a lot may be more useful than something that becomes not. OTOH count of citations is not necessarily a measure of quality, because the field/domain might be small.